# How date command keep tracking time

Tags: linux, date, time

I got a weird scenario in which the date of my computer is getting the wrong time (and he keeps fixing the time but still keep repeating this issue)

let me share with you an example who make this much more understandable:
let's say I'm running this command:

```
watch -n 1 'date'
```

this is my output:

- Sun Jun 14 08:29:44 CDT 2020
- Sun Jun 14 08:29:45 CDT 2020
- Sun Jun 14 08:29:46 CDT 2020
- **Sun Jun 14 08:29:50 CDT 2020**
- Sun Jun 14 08:29:51 CDT 2020
- Sun Jun 14 08:29:49 CDT 2020
- Sun Jun 14 08:29:50 CDT 2020
- Sun Jun 14 08:29:51 CDT 2020
- Sun Jun 14 08:29:52 CDT 2020

this is happening over and over again.

First, I was getting my time from an NTP server, so I thought the NTP server has an issue, but even when I turned off the NTP server this is still happening.

Second, I thought maybe the HWclock is not working well, but when I ran watch on hwclock it's working just fine

(if I run `watch hwlock;date` I can see that hwclock is working good but the date got the issue described earlier)

I'm using Linux red-hat

anyone can suggest how could I debug it?
I want to understand why it's happening, and who has the fault.

Thanks !

Comment: My system outputs properly. Anyway, you can *debug* starting by executing `date` command manually, every 1 second to check out if it reports the same

Comment: @mattia.b89 This is what they are doing with `watch -n 1 date`.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by `hwclock` "working good". Can you show an example of e.g. `watch -n 1 'date;whclock'` or something similar that shows `date` misbehaving while `hwclock` does not?

Comment: @Kusalananda When I say the hwclock is working good I mean that every 1 sec he proceeds to the next second without those skipping that date does.
I'm not near the PC now but I think it's pretty clear what I mean by that.
(In the example that I've posted on the date command, think that hwclock will show me the correct time from 08:29:44 to 08:29:52 without any skipping)

Comment: The question talks about turning off the NTP _server_ not the NTP _client_.  Given the rest of the question, this could be a translation mistake.  Please state in the question what you did to the NTP _client_, and what and how many NTP clients you are running.

Comment: @JdeBP Hi, I meant that I turned off the NTP in my client.
(I got over 100 clients connected to this NTP server and all of them are got the correct time).
it might be some issue with the translating, my question is from where date pulls the time, and who is responsible to update this source of the time.
if I'm still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo bash -c 'while sleep 1;do hwclock;date "+%F %T";echo; done'` for some seconds so that we can see hwclock working while date doesn't? It doesn't have to be the exact command. They are not going to show the same time, but the difference should be constant.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, I will do it tomorrow first thing and update here with the result.
But just let me tell you this, I've already tried it. and I saw that the hwclock is moving 1 second forward every 1 second (as expected) BUT, the date is acting as I mentioned in the post (every few seconds I get a "jump" in time and then it's reset back to the original "NOW" time)

Comment: The weirdest thing is that your clock goes back and forth. But it's ok, you don't have to provide the info. Sometimes seeing the actual output adds a new dimension that the OP might have overlooked. If you know that running that will not add anything relevant, you can skip it. It was just a suggestion to try to find the problem. You know that right now the data doesn't add up, so to find the problem you might well have to revisit your 'givens', with or without the community.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Yea I understand what you saying. The help that I was looking from the community is to understand how the date command works and where he getting the data from. (I tried strace & ltrace but I still can't understand where the time data is coming from)

Comment: @Kusalananda: I believe that mattia.b89’s point is that `watch` ***uses*** the system clock to run a command periodically, so its behavior is undefined when the system clock is misbehaving.  Using `watch -n 1 date` to diagnose a problem with the system clock is like using a tool to calibrate itself.  (For example, I once used a stopwatch to calibrate / tune an NTP server (on an air-gapped network).)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update, it was a hardware issue (something with the CPU itself)
replacing the machine (a server) solved the issue.

Thanks anyway for the answers!